# 64 bit Open Source Windows strace alternative

Tags: windows, open-source

I know process monitor is basically a GUI version of [linux strace](http://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/). However, I'd like a command line version that writes to stdout or a file, and works on 64 bit windows.

Strace for 32 bit windows exists:

- [drstrace.exe](http://drmemory.org/strace_for_windows.html)
- [ntstrace](http://www.zoneos.com/ntstrace.htm)
- [ospy](https://code.google.com/p/ospy/) GUI bases more like a procmon alternative and 32 bit only.

Answer (score 1):

[stracent.exe](http://ih.logicodu.com/?BH=projects&H=strace.htm) seems to fit the bill. However, it lacks any form of filtering, and doesn't attache to the python.exe that ships with 3.4.2. However, it works with python 2.7.9.